# Bezout-If two curves intersect at $m\cdot n$ points then the intersection multiplicity is $1$

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-curves, curves

In my lecture notes, after the Bezout theorem there is the following collary:

If the plane projective curves, $x=V(F), y=V(G)$, intersect at exactly $m \cdot n$ discrete points, then the intersection multiplicity is at each point one. (the points are simple)

The proof is the following: $I(P, x \cap y)=1, \forall P \in x \cap y$, so $m_P(x) \cdot m_P(y) \leq I(P, x \cap y)=1$

$\Rightarrow m_P(x)=1, m_P(y)=1, \forall P \in x \cap y$ .

Can you explain to me this collary??

$$$$

**Edit:**

An other collary is the following:

Let $C_F=V(F)$ and $C_G=V(G)$ two algebraic curves of degree $n$ and that the two curves intersect in $n^2$ points. We suppose that exactly $m \cdot n$ from these belong to an irreducible curve of degree $m<n$. Then the remaining $n(n-m)$ belong to a curve of degree $n-m$.

$$$$

What does it mean that "$m \cdot n$ from these belong to an irreducible " ???

Answer (score 0):

The proof in your notes looks a little muddled. I'm assuming, although it's not explicitly stated in the question, that $m$ is the degree of $F$ and $n$ is the degree of $G$. The point is that you know that the sum of all the intersection multiplicities is $mn$, and that each intersection point contributes intersection multiplicity $\geq 1$. If you have $mn$ integers each $\geq 1$, and they add up to $mn$, then clearly each integer was in fact exactly $1$.

Comment: I will read it later, because I am mixed up right now. :( Bezout Theorem:
$$$$
$K$ algebraic closed
$$$$
Let $X=V(F), y=V(G)$ two projective curves of $\mathbb{P}^2(K)$ with degree $m$ and $n$ respectively that do not have a common component. Then:


$$\sum_{P \in \mathbb{P}^2(\mathbb{C})} I(P, F \cap G)=mn$$


We are looking at the algebraic curves X,y but we find the intersection multiplicity of F,G. Why?

Comment: I added also an other collary that I don't understand. Can you help me?